# Interactive debugging of pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Is it possible to attach an interactive shell/prompt to a provisioned server/agent of a pipeline to debug. So for example if I want to locate a file and I search for it with cd & ls(I know not the best way but that is not the point), I would have to run the pipeline a couple of times to find what I am looking for.
Same goes for commands if the pipeline server is using a different os than mine I would like to debug it in realtime and not run the pipeline agent 5-10 times until I found the correct flags.

Is that possible in any way? Or would that be a wrong usage of a pipeline server?

We use Azure DevOps Pipelines but I think this applies for other pipelines as-well.

Answer (score 1):

That's not possible in Azure Pipelines as far as I know. You could install a self hosted agent on your own machine or easy accessible server and add extra default logging. I use a custom template with a lot of logging and checks which I run can run by setting a parameter. It just takes a few seconds extra but it usually provides me with all of the information I need when I need to debug something.